# What is wrong with my jump logic?

Tags: java, game-physics

For some reason, every time I jump in my the game I'm making, the jump gets shorter than the previous jump. Jumps start long and majestic (my game is set in space) and after about 10 jumps, my character is literally twitching against the ground because the jump is practically less than one pixel in height. I honestly cannot find out what is wrong with it, but I feel like it has something to do with the way I find deltaTime. Please help. I'm usually able to solve my own problems with a bit of troubleshooting and/or a bit of Googling, but I honestly don't know what's wrong and it all looks logical to me.

Sorry for the lack of comments. As you can probably tell from my nasty styles of implementing, this is kinda just a quick-write project so I don't really care much to look at the code later. I'm making this mainly to learn and practice Java.

I know there are a lot of out of class references so if you need to see one (I believe I included the important ones), just let me know.

Player Class (which extends Entity):

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import main.Main;
import scenes.Scene;
import threads.Time;

public class Player extends Entity {

    private Scene scene;

    private int HorizontalAxis = 0;

    public float speed = 0.5f;
    public float gravity = 0.001f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 1f;

    private float moveVelX = 0, moveVelY = 0;

    public Player(String name, String tag, int x, int y, int w, int h, String spritePath, Scene scene) {
        super(name, tag, x, y, w, h, spritePath);
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public void Update() {

        //System.out.println(isGrounded());

        if (Main.keyInput.getKeyState("MoveLeft")) {
            HorizontalAxis = -1;
        }
        if (Main.keyInput.getKeyState("MoveRight")) {
            HorizontalAxis = 1;
        }
        if (Main.keyInput.getKeyState("MoveLeft") == Main.keyInput.getKeyState("MoveRight")) {
            HorizontalAxis = 0;
        }

        moveVelX = (HorizontalAxis * speed);

        if (isGrounded()) {
            moveVelY = 0;

            if (Main.keyInput.getKeyState("Jump") || Main.keyInput.getKeyState("JumpAlt")) {
                moveVelY = -jumpSpeed;
            }
        } else {
            moveVelY += gravity * Time.deltaTime.getSeconds();
        }

        setTrueX(getTrueX() + moveVelX);
        setTrueY(getTrueY() + moveVelY);
        System.out.println(moveVelY);
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(getSprite(), getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), Main.display);
    }

    public boolean isGrounded() {
        ArrayList<Entity> groundEntities = scene.FindEntitiesWithTag("Ground");

        if (groundEntities.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < groundEntities.size(); i++) {
                if (this.hitbox.intersects(groundEntities.get(i).hitbox)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        } else {
            System.err.println("There is no ground in the scene!");
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Entity Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import main.Main;

public class Entity {

    public static enum AutoDrawTypes { NONE, RECTANGLE, RECTANGLE_ROUND, OVAL };
    public static AutoDrawTypes autoDrawType = Entity.AutoDrawTypes.NONE;

    public String name;
    public String tag;

    protected float x, y;

    protected int arcWidth, arcHeight;

    protected Rectangle hitbox = new Rectangle();
    protected Image sprite;

    protected Color color;

    public Entity(String tag, String name, int x, int y, int w, int h, String spritePath) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        hitbox.setBounds((int)(getTrueX() - Camera.getX()), (int)(getTrueY() - Camera.getY()), w, h);
        setSprite(spritePath);
        this.autoDrawType = Entity.AutoDrawTypes.NONE;
    }

    public Entity(String tag, String name, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        hitbox.setBounds((int)(getTrueX() - Camera.getX()), (int)(getTrueY() - Camera.getY()), w, h);
        this.autoDrawType = Entity.AutoDrawTypes.NONE;
    }

    public Entity(String tag, String name, int x, int y, int w, int h, Entity.AutoDrawTypes autoDrawType, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        hitbox.setBounds((int)(getTrueX() - Camera.getX()), (int)(getTrueY() - Camera.getY()), w, h);
        this.autoDrawType = autoDrawType;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Entity(String tag, String name, int x, int y, int w, int h, Entity.AutoDrawTypes autoDrawType, Color color, int arcWidth, int arcHeight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        hitbox.setBounds((int)(getTrueX() - Camera.getX()), (int)(getTrueY() - Camera.getY()), w, h);
        this.autoDrawType = autoDrawType;
        this.color = color;
        this.arcWidth = arcWidth;
        this.arcHeight = arcHeight;
    }

    public void UpdatePositionRelativeToCamera() {
        hitbox.setBounds((int)(getTrueX() - Camera.getX()), (int)(getTrueY() - Camera.getY()), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public Entity() {

    }

    public void Update() {
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        if (autoDrawType == Entity.AutoDrawTypes.RECTANGLE) {
            g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        if (autoDrawType == Entity.AutoDrawTypes.RECTANGLE_ROUND) {
            g.fillRoundRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), arcWidth, arcHeight);
        }
        if (autoDrawType == Entity.AutoDrawTypes.OVAL) {
            g.fillOval(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public void setTrueX(float x) {this.x = x;}
    public void setTrueY(float y) {this.y = y;}
    public void setX(int x) {hitbox.x = x;}
    public void setY(int y) {hitbox.y = y;}
    public void setWidth(int width) {hitbox.width = width;}
    public void setHeight(int height) {hitbox.height = height;}
    public void setSprite(String path) {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        if (tk == null) {
            System.err.println("Default Toolkit could not be fetched.");
            return;
        }
        sprite = tk.getImage(Main.class.getResource(path));
        if (sprite == null) {
            System.err.println("Image not found at + '" + path + "'. Check path in resources folder.");
            return;
        }
    }

    public float getTrueX() {return this.x;}
    public float getTrueY() {return this.y;}
    public int getX() {return hitbox.x;}
    public int getY() {return hitbox.y;}
    public int getWidth() {return hitbox.width;}
    public int getHeight() {return hitbox.height;}
    public Image getSprite() {return sprite;}

}
```

Timing Class (which is run as a thread at the start of the application):

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Time implements Runnable {

    public static boolean running = false;

    public static Duration deltaTime = Duration.ZERO;
    public static Instant beginTime = Instant.now();

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            deltaTime = Duration.between(beginTime, Instant.now());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I don't really care much to look at the code later"` -- in this case, you're right, you don't have to worry how good the code looks or how well commented it is, **unless you're asking others (us!) to review it for you**.

Comment: OK question, where in the code above do you actually have the logic for jumping? Please explain this code, code that we unfortunately can't compile nor run as it has dependencies that we're not privy to.

Comment: your delta time is not a delta time as beginTime is never updated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read through ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and make sure that if you want help from other, real humans beings, you put in the effort to show an [mcve]. This will tell us your care enough to actually find out what's wrong, and lets us get straight to the point because the code you show is exactly the code involved.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it. It was the way I calculated deltaTime. I decided just to remove deltaTime and reduce the gravity (even though it's already insanely small lol). That fixed the weird "smaller jumps over time" bug thing.

Comment: You may wish to consider deleting the question

Comment: You must use deltatime, otherwise gravity will vary depending on framerate. However deltatime should be the amount of time since last update, not the amount of time since you started the program.

Comment: @spectras In a physically accurate simulation there's no dependency between the acceleration and the amount of time since you left the ground, so the time delta might not even be necessary.

Comment: @templatetypedef> acceleration no, but when you update speed, you're integrating it over the time from last update to current update. You have to know how long that interval is. Consider: if you `update()` 100 times per second and if you `update()` 20 times per second, you still want the speed to have changed by the same amount after 1 second has elapsed.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't take into account the delta time, the game becomes dependent upon the exact environment that your are developing and testing in. Once you port it to an environment with higher/lower frame rate, the games behavior will not be consistent. Removing the dependency may fix the current issue, but will probably require refactoring as the game grows.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code for causing the player to fall down:

```
    moveVelY += gravity * Time.deltaTime.getSeconds();
```

Notice that this causes the player's y velocity to increase by an amount that increases as a function of time. That is, it's as if gravity is constantly increasing as time passes. As a result, if you jump early on, it's like jumping on the moon, and if you jump later it's like jumping on Jupiter or the surface of a neutron star.

To fix this, remove the dependency on the current time. Just increase the y velocity by the gravity term, which should probably just be a fixed constant unless you're doing something cool with the world physics.